# How to get sums of table column for different groups of data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I have the following table:

```
Code |  Name     | Store    |  Balance 
------------------------------------- 
56   | product1  |   NY     |   10
56   | product1  |   CH     |   100
56   | product1  |   DE     |   1000
56   | product1  |   AL     |   10000
56   | product1  |   PR     |   10
56   | product1  |   ST     |   10
56   | product1  |   OH     |   10000

57   | product2  |   NY     |   10
57   | product2  |   CH     |   100
57   | product2  |   DE     |   1000
57   | product2  |   AL     |   10000
57   | product2  |   PR     |   10
57   | product2  |   ST     |   10
57   | product2  |   OH     |   10000

58   | product3  |   NY     |   10
58   | product3  |   CH     |   100
58   | product3  |   DE     |   1000
58   | product3  |   AL     |   10000
58   | product3  |   PR     |   10
58   | product3  |   ST     |   10
58   | product3  |   OH     |   10000
```

What I need to get is:

```
Code |  Name     | Store       |  Total Balance By Stores
-----------------------------------------------------
56   | product1  |   NY,PR,ST  |   30
56   | product1  |   CH        |   100
56   | product1  |   DE        |   1000
56   | product1  |   AL,OH     |   20000

57   | product2  |   NY,PR,ST  |   30
57   | product2  |   CH        |   100
57   | product2  |   DE        |   1000
57   | product2  |   AL,OH     |   20000

58   | product3  |   NY,PR,ST  |   30
58   | product3  |   CH        |   100
58   | product3  |   DE        |   1000
58   | product3  |   AL,OH     |   20000
```

By the words - They are 7 stores from which 3 are in one country (NY,PR,ST), 2 are in another country (AL,OH) and 2 are in other individual countries (CH and DE). 
What I need is to get total balance, i.e. SUM for the group of the NY,PR,ST (for each individual product), the same for AL,OH, and also balance for CH and DE.

I have already tried things such as `GROUP BY`, `UNION`, etc. but all far from a satisfiable result

The database server in question is MS SQLSERVER.

The solution can be anything e.g. a stored procedure or SQL query

EDIT: DELETED the wrong store's names from the question (Before it was A1, A2, A3 so all the solutions with the LEFT were fine.) I am very sorry for this mistake...

The solution with LEFT will not work with the corrected names.

I'm very sorry for this confusion - I tried to keep things simple so I've named the stores here as A, B, C, D... I didn't have a clue of the LEFT function and what confusion it will cause... So sorry once more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is an answer to your edited question**.
As I mentioned in a comment, the way you designed your database is certain (not almost) that will cause future problems when there will be changes, like new stores or new stores in new countries. 
Anyway, a solution to the current state is this:

```
select
  t.code Code, 
  t.name Name, 
  t.storegroup Store, 
  sum(t.balance) [Total Balance By Stores]
from (
  select *,
    case 
      when store in ('NY', 'PR', 'ST') then 'NY,PR,ST'
      when store in ('AL', 'OH') then 'AL,OH'
      else store
    end storegroup
  from tablename
) t
group by t.code, t.name, t.storegroup
```

Comment: Wow....great. Thank you, thank you, thank you... It is exactly what I wanted! I think there is a lot of things I must learn in SQL, e.g. I didn't know about grouping by the way of "storegroup" in your answer :-) BTW, it is not me who designed the database - the database is "as is" and I must work with it as I can :-) Thank you once more!

Answer (score 5):

You need to group by code, name and left(store, 1) and sum over balance:

```
select
  code, name, left(store, 1) store, sum(balance) [Total Balance By Stores]
from tablename
group by code, name, left(store, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! See my corrected (edited) question, please.

Comment: Your corrected question has nothing to do with the original question and all the answers you received so far. Since there is no way to distinguish between the stores the way you describe it, you'd better make changes to the design of the database and create a table where you will store countries and the stores that belong to each country. Hardcoding lists like (NY,PR,ST) is indicative of poor design and almost certain to cause problems later when you will need to add or remove stores or countries.

Answer (score 4):

First, you must construct the column that has the information as you describe - by taking the first letter:

`select left(store,1) as Store from yourtable`

Now you can include this column in your `GROUP BY`:

```
select Code,Name,left(store,1) as Store,sum(Balance ) as [Total Balance By Stores]
from yourtable
group by Code,Name,left(store,1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! See my corrected (edited) question, please.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #sum
    ([Code] int, [Name] varchar(8), [Store] varchar(2), [Balance] int)
;

INSERT INTO #sum
    ([Code], [Name], [Store], [Balance])
VALUES
    (56, 'product1', 'A1', 10),
    (56, 'product1', 'B', 100),
    (56, 'product1', 'C', 1000),
    (56, 'product1', 'D1', 10000),
    (56, 'product1', 'A2', 10),
    (56, 'product1', 'A3', 10),
    (56, 'product1', 'D2', 10000),
    (57, 'product2', 'A1', 10),
    (57, 'product2', 'B', 100),
    (57, 'product2', 'C', 1000),
    (57, 'product2', 'D1', 10000),
    (57, 'product2', 'A2', 10),
    (57, 'product2', 'A3', 10),
    (57, 'product2', 'D2', 10000),
    (58, 'product3', 'A1', 10),
    (58, 'product3', 'B', 100),
    (58, 'product3', 'C', 1000),
    (58, 'product3', 'D1', 10000),
    (58, 'product3', 'A2', 10),
    (58, 'product3', 'A3', 10),
    (58, 'product3', 'D2', 10000)
;
select Code,Name,LEFT(store,1)store ,SUM(balance) from #sum
group by Code,Name,LEFT(store,1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! See my corrected (edited) question, please.